# Listen to Physical button press from background on Wear OS

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it possible to listen for a button press from a background app running on a Wear device?
I would like to create a shortcut for an Android app so that when the user presses a physical button on a watch, the app opens on a paired device.

Thank you,
Donny

Answer (score -1):

**add to manifest receiver**

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".services.utils.SearchLongPressReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SOS_LONG_PRESS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**create BroadcastReceiver**

```
class SearchLongPressReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    
   override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
       context.startActivity(Intent(context, SosActivity::class.java))
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for SOS_LONG_PRESS or SosActivity?

Comment: No, you won't find documentation for this action.